# Sharepoint. How to access objects in RenderingTemplate

Tags: sharepoint, get

I'm working on rendering templates (Sharepoint 2010), overrided standart new/edit/display forms with my own, but I can't get objects in code-beghind from inside RenderingTemplate class.
for e.g:

```
<SharePoint:RenderingTemplate ID="ParentItemsListView" runat="server">
<Template>
    <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
        <tr><td nowrap class="class1"><asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><SharePoint:FieldLabel runat="server" ID="TitleDescriptionField"  ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="Title" /></td></tr>
    </table>
</Template>
```

I need to custom FieldLabel object.

I hope someone could help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get it like this:

```
FieldLabel fieldLabelControl= ParentItemsListView.FindControl("TitleDescriptionField") as FieldLabel;
if(fieldLabelControl != null)
{
  //Do something with it
}
```