# Dynamically Change Label Text in SharePoint Rendering Template

Tags: c#, asp.net, templates, sharepoint

If I did not have a rendering template I could add the following to my aspx page:

```
<asp:label ID="myLabel" runat="server" />
```

Then this in my code behind:

```
myLabel.Text = "Hello World";
```

But since my label is inside of a `<SharePoint:RenderingTemplate>` I am not able to access it the normal way.

Is there another way?

**Edit**: Ive found a number of articles like [this one](http://jamestsai.net/Blog/post/Using-ASPNET-Web-User-Control-with-Code-Behind-in-SharePoint.aspx) talking about creating a .dll for every rendering template.  Is it really that complicated to output a string to a page? I should clarify that I am open to all ideas.  I do not need code behind.  I simply need to output a dynamic string to the template.

Comment: I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060049/sharepoint-how-to-access-objects-in-renderingtemplate).  Hopefully it helps!

Comment: @Brian First thing I tried.  Didnt work.

Comment: Why didn't `FindControl` work? This is exactly what you should do :-) Sure you used the correct ID to find the correct control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create your own label control and work with it in any way you like.

There is an example here: [Extending the Label Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3457/Extending-the-Label-Control), but it's basically like you would extend any other control.

What I would do then: Either set the `.Text` in that custom control directly, or what would be better is to use resource files. Then you could create your won property on the label like so:

```
<Custom:label ID="myLabel" specialresource="myLabel" runat="server" />
```

And in your class you could just handle the `specialresource` property and e.g. set the `.Text` to whatever you get from the resource.